# “If you insist there be...” , is that correct? Can I use it like that?

Tags: grammar

But if you insist there be someone being judgemental, it's you,not her.

(Is that correct, or I should use “there is”, and why thank you!)

Comment: They are using *be* as imperative. *There* is just a syntactic expletive. Compare with when you say it *Let there be light!*. In your sentence the imperative is being said to be said by whoever is the *you* in that sentence.

Answer (score 1):

An interesting question. The *be* form is certainly grammatical in an utterance like "*He insisted that I **be** at the meeting*".

In such a case the verb *to insist* means to demand or require that something happens in the future. The *be* here is an example of the *[mandative subjunctive](https://www.thoughtco.com/mandative-subjunctive-term-1691299)*.

However, *to insist* also means to state or maintain very strongly that something is the case. For example:

> He insisted I was at the meeting, but I don't remember anything about it.

In such a case, the mandative subjunctive is clearly ungrammatical:

> *He insisted I be at the meeting, but I don't remember anything about it.

The utterance "*if you insist there be someone being judgemental*" is using *insist* in this second sense of asserting forcefully. So it certainly could be written as:

> If you insist that there *is* someone being judgemental....

But is it ungrammatical to use a mandative subjunctive in a clause that does not follow a mandative verb (or adjective, e.g. *It is vital that he **be** at the meeting*)?

I don't have a definitive answer to this question. The sentence seems slightly suspect to me as a British English native speaker. But a quick Google search returns a couple of examples containing the *insist there be* string in which *insist* seems to mean *maintain* or *assert*:

> - If you insist there be no nations in their mental map, they're going to identify with smaller identity groups.
> - Regardless the age of the child or "child" (if you insist there be a distinction), this man has allegedly helped take advantage and abuse minors .